# Auto adjust LinearLayout and clone LinearLayout entirely

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Good day!

I'll start with the 2 issues:

1.- I want a LinearLayour to autoadjust his content whenever necessary (Because I disabled an element on the layout).

2.- Clone a LinearLayout entirely depending on the size of an Array.

1. I have this code (yes, it is pretty big):

   ```
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textTitleScore"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:text="Votaciones"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/segoeprint"
                    android:textColor="@color/ourBlack3"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/titleFinalEvent"
                    android:textSize="28sp"/>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/constraint_team"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="activateContent"
                    android:background="@drawable/finaleventteambackground"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/ourOrange">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                        android:src="@mipmap/littlelogomc" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        android:text="Equipo 1"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/seguisbi"
                        android:textColor="@color/ourWhite"
                        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/team1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/finaleventteambackground">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/segoeprint"
                        android:textColor="@color/ourBlack3"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:text="Presentación"/>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                        <SeekBar
                            android:id="@+id/seekBarPresentation"
                            android:layout_width="240dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seekbar"
                            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"/>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="70dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/edittextbackground"
                            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/editTextPresentation"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:inputType="number"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:hint="0"/>
                        </RelativeLayout>


                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/segoeprint"
                        android:textColor="@color/ourBlack3"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:text="Servicio"/>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                        <SeekBar
                            android:id="@+id/seekBarService"
                            android:layout_width="240dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seekbar"
                            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"/>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="70dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/edittextbackground"
                            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/editTextService"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:inputType="number"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:hint="0"/>
                        </RelativeLayout>


                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/segoeprint"
                        android:textColor="@color/ourBlack3"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:text="Sabor"/>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                        <SeekBar
                            android:id="@+id/seekBarFlavour"
                            android:layout_width="240dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seekbar"
                            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"/>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="70dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/edittextbackground"
                            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/editTextFlavour"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:inputType="number"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:hint="0"/>
                        </RelativeLayout>


                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/segoeprint"
                        android:textColor="@color/ourBlack3"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:text="Imagen"/>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                        <SeekBar
                            android:id="@+id/seekBarImage"
                            android:layout_width="240dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seekbar"
                            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"/>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="70dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/edittextbackground"
                            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/editTextImage"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:inputType="number"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:hint="0"/>
                        </RelativeLayout>


                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/segoeprint"
                        android:textColor="@color/ourBlack3"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:text="Tríptico"/>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                        <SeekBar
                            android:id="@+id/seekBarTriptych"
                            android:layout_width="240dp"
                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seekbar"
                            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"/>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="70dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:background="@drawable/edittextbackground"
                            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

                            <EditText
                                android:id="@+id/editTextTriptych"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="right"
                                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:inputType="number"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:hint="0"/>
                        </RelativeLayout>


                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:enabled="false"
                        android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/ourOrange"
                        android:text="Votar"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/segoeprint"
                        android:textFontWeight="700"
                        android:textColor="@color/ourWhite"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="18sp"/>

                </LinearLayout>



            </LinearLayout>
   ```

The first RelativeLayout (+id/constraint_team), has an OnClick() event which disables or enables the next children LinearLayout (@+id/team1). But the parent LinearLayout(@+id/linear_score) doesn't adjust when I disable the children LinearLayout.

I was trying to achieve this with this code:

```
if (linearLayout.isEnabled())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++)
            {
                View v = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
                v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                v.setEnabled(false);
            }
            linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            linearLayout.setEnabled(false);
            //linearLayoutScore.getLayoutParams().height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            //ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = linearLayoutScore.getLayoutParams();
            linearLayoutScore.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            linearLayoutScore.requestLayout();
        }
```

(The comments are other unsuccessful attempts I have tried)

with this code, instead of only modifying the size of the parent LinearLayout, it modifies the entire screen to be only this parent LinearLayout. (I've read that set.LayoutParams only modify the layout height and width, but it doesn't seems to work like that).

2. For the second one I haven't found anything useful (maybe i'm just using really bad keyword on google), Basically if I receive a number, for example 3, I want to copy my child LinearLayout and my RelativeLayout (@+id/constraint_team and @+id/team1) that many times, How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why aren't you using a recyclerview

Comment: I wouldn't use RelativeLayouts. If anything, ConstraintLayouts is the way to go; but I agree with the previous user: This is what a List (RecyclerView) is for. A set of data that is bound to a set of views. When the data changes, the views are updated to reflect the change.